# New Random Number Not Generating

Tags: java, random

Hi when I run this piece of code and I return a false distance, a new random number is not generated. The same random number is continually generated, thus putting me into an infinite loop. Does anyone know why this is happening? Thank you for looking!

```
private void setRandomVerticies() 
{
    //generate 200 triangles
    this.randomVerticies = new LinkedList<TGVertex>(); 
    random.setSeed(System.currentTimeMillis());
    short x = 5000, y = 5000;
    int specT = 0;
    int vert = 0;
    int triangleCount = 0;
    int rx = 0, ry = 0;
    int sameAxis = 0;
    TGVertex check = new TGVertex(x,y);
    for (int i = 1; i <= 600; i++)
    {
      for (;;)
      {
        rx = random.nextInt(); 
        ry = random.nextInt();
        System.out.println("generate a new random number please");
        if(i == 1) break;
        if (specT == 1) //approximately 50 triangles will have 2 vertices against the edge
        {
          if       (sameAxis == 0  || sameAxis == 1)  { rx = 0; 
          }else if (sameAxis == 2  || sameAxis == 3)  { ry = 0;
          }else if (sameAxis == 4  || sameAxis == 5)  { rx = tImage.getWidth()-1;
          }else if (sameAxis == 6  || sameAxis == 7)  { ry = tImage.getHeight()-1; }
          check = new TGVertex(rx, ry);
          if (!randomVerticies.contains(check))
          {
            if (vert == 2 && distance(check, randomVerticies.get(i-2)))
            {
              sameAxis++;
              if (sameAxis == 8) sameAxis = 0;
              break; //breaks while loop if new vertex is chosen
            } 
            else if (vert == 1)
            {
              sameAxis++;
              if (sameAxis == 8) sameAxis = 0;
              break; //breaks while loop if new vertex is chosen    
            }
          }
        }
        rx = (short)(rx & 0x1FF);
        ry = (short)(rx & 0x19D);
        check = new TGVertex(rx, ry);
        System.out.println("rx = " + rx + " ry = " + ry);
        System.out.println("check = " + check.getX() + ", " + check.getY());
        System.out.println("randomVert = " + randomVerticies.get(i-2).getX() + ", " + randomVerticies.get(i-2).getY());
        if (!randomVerticies.contains(check) && distance(check, randomVerticies.get(i-2))) break; //breaks while loop if new vertex is chosen
      }

      String sliceX = Integer.toHexString(this.width()-1);
      String sliceY = Integer.toHexString(this.height()-1);
      int sX = (int) Integer.parseInt(sliceX, util.Global.HEX);
      int sY = (int) Integer.parseInt(sliceY, util.Global.HEX);  
      x = (short) (rx & sX); 
      y = (short) (ry & sY);
      //System.out.println("("+x+", "+y+")");
      randomVerticies.add( new TGVertex(x, y) );

      if (i % 3 == 0) triangleCount++;
      if (triangleCount == 2 && vert < 3 )
      { 
        specT = 1;
        vert++;
      } 
      if (vert == 3)
      { 
        specT = 0;
        vert = 0;
        triangleCount = 0;
      }
    }
}
```

Here is the output, as you can see the randomVert never changes values.

```
rx = 196 ry = 132
check = 196, 132
randomVert = 225, 392
generate a new random number please
rx = 383 ry = 285
check = 383, 285
randomVert = 225, 392
generate a new random number please
rx = 328 ry = 264
check = 328, 264
randomVert = 225, 392
generate a new random number please
rx = 102 ry = 4
check = 102, 4
randomVert = 225, 392
generate a new random number please
rx = 197 ry = 133
check = 197, 133
randomVert = 225, 392
generate a new random number please
rx = 62 ry = 28
check = 62, 28
randomVert = 225, 392
generate a new random number please
rx = 295 ry = 261
check = 295, 261
randomVert = 225, 392
generate a new random number please
rx = 142 ry = 140
check = 142, 140
randomVert = 225, 392
generate a new random number please
rx = 261 ry = 261
check = 261, 261
randomVert = 225, 392
```

Comment: That is one of most of the complex pieces of code I've ever seen. Wow!

Comment: Does this compile? on line 5 you call random.setSeed(), but isn't declared until 13... I'd not use milliseconds seeding as Random already seeded nano seconds and unique instance salt.

Comment: This compiles, sorry for the confusion with the extra Random call. It has been removed and updated in the edit.

Comment: Does TGVertex implement equals() ?

Comment: It could implement equals().

Comment: I am probably late to the game (4 years late actually), but I found using Random is not perfect solution - especially if range from which random number is generated is relatively small. Implementing [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle) could be more effective for tasks like this and might help to avoid duplicates for n and n+1 numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're creating back-to-back new instances of `Random` in your loop.  Just create one (outside the loop!), and ask it for random numbers when you need new values.  Think of it as being like digging a well - you don't dig a new well each time you want a drink of water, you dig one well and go back to it for as many drinks as you need.

Comment: Hi pjs, I took your advise and edited the code, as you can now see above; however, I am still experiencing the same issue as before. Thank you!

Comment: Have you stepped through with a debugger or added print statements to confirm that the issue is with the random numbers?  Also, it's considered bad form to edit the code in your question - make an addendum with any revisions, but you should leave your original code intact.

Comment: Yes I will add the output to the question.

Comment: I'm specifically talking about the values of `rx` and `ry` immediately after you generate them. If they are in fact random, then you've eliminated that as a source for your problems.

Comment: The output has been added.

Comment: pjs, the first generation is random, but when the loop fails to break; as it should for that condition, a new random number is not generated, I need a new random number generated to see if it falls into the correct bounds.

Comment: So `rx` and `ry` are in fact being randomly generated now. Time to step through with a debugger to see why you always get the same value, but it's not because of the randomness.

Comment: So when rx = random.nextInt() is called, it shouldnt be displaying a new random integer?

Comment: When `rx = random.nextInt()` is called it should be displaying a new value, and the output you provided says it does. It's your logic for randomVert that's messed up, not the random numbers.

Comment: Ahhh yes, I see what you mean. I should have seen that I think I'm just tired, thanks for the help. I should be fine. I will check your answer since you awakened my eye haha! Thanks again.

Comment: @pjs: The code was edited to remove the instantiation of Random, so your answer doesn't apply anymore.  There's still a problem if `setRandomVerticies()` is called multiple times at once, since the generator is reseeded each time with `System.currentTimeMillis()`.

Comment: +1 for the Well analogy. I never knew how to explain that concept :)